# How to revert single file in SVN to previous revision after directory move

Tags: svn

I would like to revert a single file `file.F90` in SVN to a previous revision. However, prior to last commit I have renamed (moved) directories. Now the standard command

```
svn up -r 16 branches/new/file.F90
```

simply deletes the new version of the file, but cannot fetch the old version. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Before the last commit directory `branches/old` was moved to `branches/new` with `svn mv` command.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `svn cat` to print out the file, and use the `@` to *pin* the directory layout to a particular version of the file:

```
$ svn cat -r16 $REPO/branches/old/file.F90@16 > file.F90
```

Comment: Potentially there is something missing in your command. When I execute it I get an error: `svn: E155007: '/branches/old/file.F90' is not a working copy`. Do I have to use the variable `$REPO` literally as it is?

Comment: The `$REPO` is an environment variable that represents the root URL of your repository. If you're on Windows, it'll be `%RRPO%`. Sorry, I usually do that because I don't know what the root URL of the repo is. (And I do define that as a variable on my systems). You need to use something like `http://svn.corp.local/svn/branches/old/file.F90@16`